# Null dereference on function with struct pointer as input

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, nullreferenceexception, dereference

Following is legacy code.

```
void InitializeStruct(someStruct* str); //function declaration
```

Now this is used as follows:

```
someStruct* myStruct = NULL;
int counter = 0;

int count = GetCount(); //obtains some count

if(count != 0)
{
    myStruct = (someStruct*) malloc(count * sizeof(someStruct));
}

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    if(some condition)  //for some condition
    {
        InitializeStruct(&myStruct[counter]); //null dererferenced here
        counter ++;
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to fix this?
Size of `myStruct` is not known beforehand. I guess, the reason it complains about dereferencing null is because, what if `count = 0`.

Comment: This wouldn't compile: `struct* mystruct = NULL;` Did you post the actual code?

Comment: Wrap it in a small RAII class that calls `InitializeStruct` in the constructor, then use a `std::array<wrappedstruct, 3>`, or `std::vector` if you don't know the size or it could change. No loop necessary to initialize the elements and no cleanup required if you account for that in the wrapper.

Comment: `InitializeStruct(someStruct* str);` is not a function declaration; function declarations must have a return type.  (C once permitted function declarations with no return type, but C++ never has).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That was a typo. I have corrected it. Also I have added some more as in the actual code where the size of the array is not known beforehand. So can I just do `array = new mystruct;` instead of `array = new mystruct[3];` in this case?

Comment: @Matt McNabb I corrected that too. Had overlooked it. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Request the moderators to remove the hold

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space to your array of three `mystruct`, like this:

```
mystruct *array = NULL;
...
array = new mystruct[3]; // Allocate memory for the array
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
{
    InitializeStruct(&array[i]);
}
...
delete[] array; // When you are done with the array, free the memory
```

Comment: Complain about it all you want, but dasblinkenlight is right. No space is allocated in the original psedo code. If you don't want to play dynamically as dasblikenlight coded up, you need to declare it as an array. One way is no more correct then another so long as the memory is actually generated. Cheers.

Comment: `mystruct array[3];` would be somewhat simpler. If runtime resizing is needed then `vector<mystruct> array(3);`

Comment: @Matt McNabb Vector idea is good. Do I need to add some size in parenthesis i.e. `array(3)`. `vector<mystruct> array;` should also work....isn't it?

Comment: @ontherocks the 3 means to resize it to 3 at the start. If you leave that off then you have to resize it later, maybe in the same function as the initialize.